# Why is my vscode 1.38.1 showing 'predefined type not defined or imported' when opening .NET Core 3.0 bare console app on Ubuntu 19

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core-3.0, ubuntu-19.04

I installed .NET core 3.0 SDK and created an console app with `dotnet new console`. This is the project file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

The app runs successfully with `dotnet run`. When I open it in Visual Studio Code, all types including `Program`, `void`, `string`, `Console` are underlined indicating errors. The error is always the same. This example shows the `string` error

```
Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported (CS0518) [myproject]
```

I've tried:

- `dotnet clean` and `dotnet restore`/`dotnet build`
- Manually removing `bin`, `obj`, `.vscode` and restoring
- Restoring from vscode itself
- Installed the latest version of the C# extension and of VS Code

Note that `.netcoreapp2.2` apps open fine.

Here is some environment info:

```
$ code --version
1.38.1
b37e54c98e1a74ba89e03073e5a3761284e3ffb0
x64
```

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  19.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.19.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  95a0a61858

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.2.402 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  3.0.100 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:        19.04
Codename:       disco
```

Comment: My colleague experiences the same issue on windows 10 with the same .NET Core 3, vscode and extension versions.

Comment: Same issue here, same versions, any .netcore 3 project... builds and runs fine, but is unusable when the editor doesn't understand anything.

Comment: @SteveMcNiven-Scott I just saw that the [vscode C# extension 1.21.4](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode#whats-new-in-1214) is coming soon and it has improved support for .NET Core 3. This might fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Problem seems to be resolved in VS Code 1.39.0 even after removing mono-devel and its dependencies

**Original:**

Apparently, this is a C# Extension issue. As [C# Extension fails only for netcoreapp3.0 GA #3289](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3289#issuecomment-534396993) issue comment suggest, installing `Mono 6.0.0` (on linux or Mac) fixes the issue. I can confirm that.

Install Mono 6 from [here](https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/)
or for Ubuntu 18.04 and higher run the following:

```
sudo apt install gnupg ca-certificates
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu stable-bionic main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
sudo apt update
```

```
sudo apt install mono-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

I have dropped all other dotnet SDKs, leaving only 3.0.100 available.
That did the trick.

Linux Mint, latest VSCode.